# Is it possible to get the result generated by eclipse link?

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have this entity with Generationtype table working..

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "app_users_pk")
@TableGenerator( name = "appseqstore", table = "app_seq_store", pkColumnName = "app_seq_name", pkColumnValue = "app_users_pk", valueColumnName = "app_seq_value", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1 )
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE,generator = "appseqstore")
private Long appUsersPk;
```

when I execute a create command this is what eclipselink do.. (on my glassfish log)

```
UPDATE app_seq_store SET app_seq_value = app_seq_value + ? WHERE app_seq_name = ?
    bind => [1, app_users_pk]
SELECT app_seq_value FROM app_seq_store WHERE app_seq_name = ?
    bind => [app_users_pk]
INSERT INTO app_users (app_users_pk, username) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [33, try lang]
SELECT app_users_pk, username FROM app_users
```

When I check the mysql log I found that eclipselink make 3 queries
1st is to update the table by incrementing by 1
2nd get the incremented value
and 3rd insert using the the incremented value 
(on mysql query log)

```
SET autocommit=0
UPDATE app_seq_store SET app_seq_value = app_seq_value + 1 WHERE app_seq_name = 'app_users_pk'
SELECT app_seq_value FROM app_seq_store WHERE app_seq_name = 'app_users_pk'
INSERT INTO app_users (app_users_pk, username) VALUES (33, 'try lang')
commit
SET autocommit=1
```

now I see that eclipselink issued an "select" query..
is it possible to get the result from that query? because i also want that key to be used in other related table, or is their any other way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: The object you have persisted will have the appUsersPk set when done.

Comment: so theres no way i could get the value from the "Select" statement?

Comment: What are you after exactly?  The value is placed in the object you just created, so yes you can retrieve it.  If you want to intercept the value from the sequence query, you can hook into EclipseLink internals, but there is no way to be sure which thread is executing the sequence query.  Sounds like you just need to setup a foreign key, and JPA will handle setting the value for you.

Comment: just the result of that select statement(33 in my case)... i tried to get the value after its created but its null  public void create() {
        persist(PersistAction.CREATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Users").getString("AppUsersCreated"));
        if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
           // items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
            items = getFacade().getUsers();
            }  
        System.out.println(selected.getAppUsersPk());
        System.out.println(selected.getUsername());
        System.out.println(selected.toString());
        
    }

Comment: can you give me some idea of what you are suggesting? because i have no idea how to do that..  by the-way thanks for the time answering my question.. i just don't know how to do that..